# How to create a dynamic Wrapper?

Tags: java, wrapper, dynamic-programming, dynamic-proxy

In some parts of my Program I need to pass around a set of Objects (also some primitive types) between my classes.

For every new combination I have to create a pretty "stupid" wrapper-class which just contains two or three fields. (int, String or today I've got a int, String, Date).

All they contain is an empty and a full constructor and each field has its getter/setter.
I came across Java dynamic proxies which is praised as a solution for my problem. It appears to be impressive and mighty - I could find some fancy examples how to control robots or fetch changes in beans, yet nothing for my original purpose only to transfer a simple wrapper object between two classes.

Is there a tutorial for this kind of issue?

Comment: For one thing, you do realise that getters/setters/constructors are optional and can actually be harmful in cases like this? (And by "harmful" I don't mean your program won't work; I just mean it will be really annoying to write)

Comment: have you consider yto use generics?

Comment: A java proxy is for intercepting calls to an object that implements an interface..  which does not sound like what you want.

Comment: building on user902383's suggestion,  Scala does something similar.  It creates N classes, all called Tuple1, Tuple2, Tuple3 and so forth and then uses generics on those to give the effect that you are after.

Comment: @immibis Can you be more specific please? What do you mean by "harmful". Usually I just auto-generate most of the class in NetBeans

Comment: @ChrisK I have never worked with them before and so far no idea how to use them properly. But try googeling "Dynamic Wrapper Java" - the proxies are what you get... :-/

Comment: @Qohelet an example use of a Java proxy would be say, if you wanted to log every time a method on an object is invoked (so long as that method is declared on an interface that is, as that is a restriction of java.lang.reflect.Proxy).  What java.lang.reflect.Proxy does not do is dynamically create a new composite data type.  In your situation I would consider user902383's solution, carry on as you are or use an Object array and drink a toast to type safety ;)

Comment: The confusion with java.lang.reflect.Proxy  probably comes about because java.lang.reflect.Proxy generates a wrapper object of a defined type (implementation detail).  The goal of it however is to intercept method calls of a known type against an existing instance of an object.

Comment: @Qohelet it's harmful in that it makes it harder to write your program, and has no benefits (in this case).

Comment: @immibis: Why? Please be more specific

Comment: @Qohelet because you have to write all the getters and setters, and the constructor, and type slightly more each time you want to access a field.

Comment: @immibis I barely write the getter/setter on my own. NetBeans does that for me. And usually it's really accurate =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i meantion in comments, consider to use generic.

You need to have object which holds two custom types, 
here we go:

```
    class Pair<F,S> {
    private F first;
    private S second;

    Pair(F first, S second){
       this.first = first;
      this.second= second;
    }

   public F getFirst(){
   return first;
   }

   public S getSecond(){
   return second;
   }
}
```

How to use it? it is simple, `Pair<String,Integer> pair1 = new Pair<>("This is One",1);`

Comment: Actually, as you say it - no, I haven't thought of that yet. Great idea. Seems sometimes you can't see see the wood for the trees =)